# Highcharts heatmap points with transparency depending on value

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am trying to make a heatmap showing shot frequencies in the NHL by coordinate of the shot. I set a background image of the chart to be this image: [image: NHL rink image] Which lines up perfectly to the coordinate system. This is the result when I put data over it:

[image: NHL rink with data]

Here is the colorAxis settings I am using (colors go from white to red)

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: '#FF0000'
}
```

Is there any way to set minColor to be transparent? I would love if I could see the rink image better if shot counts in that location are near 0. Other places in highcharts seem to set colors to `null` whenever they want transparency, however that doesn't seem to work for this parameter.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you could remove the white of the background image(make  transparent) and overlay it on the heat map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a statistical point of view, `minColor: '#FFFFFF';` is actually your **outlier**. You are most likely expecting a heat map color tone  **between** white and red.

If the shot counts near zero (outliers) are not that important to see in the heat map; just increase the minimum meaningful shot counts in your code like;

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 3,
    minColor: '#FFFFFF',
    maxColor: '#FF0000'
}
```

If you still need the real transparency; you can use `rgba(255,255,255,0)`;

```
colorAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
    maxColor: '#FF0000'
}
```

The last parameter is the **alpha** or **opacity** that ranges from **0** (fully transparent) to **1** (fully opaque).